# how to resize product image on woocommerce?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

https://kairaweb.com/documentation/product-image-sizes/

I tried to try the solution here.But catalog,single product and tumbnails product options here aren't in my settings.

So,how to resize product image on woocommerce?

[screenshoots](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V6nHF.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

In new WooCommerce version, they are shifted to 'Appearance > Customize > WooCommerce > Product Images'. Hope this helps.

Comment: Hey,thanks! yes,there is.But i have a new problem.changed size settings and save but still like the old size

Comment: You may want to regenerate the thumbnails, try this plugin - https://wordpress.org/plugins/regenerate-thumbnails/.

Comment: Are you customizing WooCommerce in your theme? Would you mind posting the URL and the size you changed?

Comment: i try everything.I added a screenshot.I am saving but it doesnt change.

Comment: In the screenshot you seems changed the row & column settings and not the dimensions?